# How to get the following foreign key to work in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand about foreign keys in firebase and trying to get the following code to work but I seem to be getting a id could be nulled message. I can insert the user's information into the database but there seems to be a problem selecting the id of the child. It says that the information has been saved successfully but I don't understand why it is not updating in the database...

```
public class AddTrackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewArtistName;
    EditText editTextTrackname;
    SeekBar seekBarRating;

    Button buttonAddTrack;

    ListView listViewTracks;

    DatabaseReference databaseTracks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_track);

        textViewArtistName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewArtistName);
        editTextTrackname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTrackName);
        seekBarRating = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarRating);

        buttonAddTrack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddTrack);
        listViewTracks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTracks);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String id = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.ARTIST_ID);
        String name = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.ARTIST_NAME);

        textViewArtistName.setText(name);

        databaseTracks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tracks").child(id);

        buttonAddTrack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveTrack();
            }
        });
    }
    private void saveTrack() {
        String trackName = editTextTrackname.getText().toString().trim();
        int rating = seekBarRating.getProgress();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(trackName)) {
            String id = databaseTracks.push().getKey();

            Track track = new Track(id, trackName, rating);

            assert id != null;
            databaseTracks.child(id).setValue(track);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Track saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Track name should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc31V.png)

Comment: I forgot to provide the url in the getInstance();.... apologies

Comment: Why do you say it's not updated? I see a screenshot that contains some data. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, hello and thanks for replying but for some reason, I needed to add my firebase url for it to work... I don't know why and what is getReference() here? Sometimes I noticed that it won't work unless I leave it empty..

Comment: They have used tracks here in the getReference()

Comment: Always, leave it empty. Does it always work this way?

Comment: So far, it is working this way but in some of my other classes, it does work when I add something in it...